# For Loop functionality wont work to append <option> to a <select> tag

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I do not understand why the code that is commented out works to append an option to the select tag, but when I try to create an array and use a for loop to add all values of the array as options, the code does not work. If I am missing something simple, I apologize. Thank you in advance.

```js
//var testing ="testing value"
//$('#test').append('<option>'+testing+'</option>');

var testArray = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

for(var i=0, i < testArray.length, i++) {
  var value = testArray[i];
  $('#test').append('<option>'+value+'</option>');
  }
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<select id="test">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Because `,` is not the same as `;`. Change `for(var i=0, i < testArray.length, i++)` to `for(var i=0; i < testArray.length; i++)` - [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: So yes, it was a simple mistake. My apologies, and thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is , . Define variable out side the loop and append markup once.

```js
 var testArray = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
 var html = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
   var value = testArray[i];
   html += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
 }
 $('#test').append(html);
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<select id="test">
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I saw this as a suggestion in some other posts and had no success implementing it to work with my code, but that could have been because I used commas instead of semicolons. I do have a question though. When you keep adding to the html variable arent you simply  adding onto the string that is html with each proceeding value from the array?

Comment: append method each time it goes through that loop. That's bad because it will keep doing it every time and slowing you down. It's better to go through the loop and save what you want to append to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(testArray, function(key, value) {   
 $('#test')
      .append($('<option>', { value : key })
      .text(value)); 
});
```